# applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools configurations does not apply in virtual machine scale set

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VMSS which I deployed using ARM templates. This is the `networkProfile` block under VMSS resource section.

```
             "networkProfile": {
                 "networkInterfaceConfigurations": [
                     {
                         "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
                         "properties": {
                             "primary": true,
                             "ipConfigurations": [
                                 {
                                     "name": "[concat(variables('VMSSName'), '-ipconfig')]",
                                     "properties": {
                                         "subnet": {
                                             "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                                          },
                                         "applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools": "[variables('AppGatewayBackendAddressPool')]"
                                         }
                                     }
                                 ]
                             }
                         }
                     ]
                 },
```

In Variable section, if I use `resourceId()` function and provide values from parameters then it does not apply the configuration in VMSS. for example:

```
"AppGatewayBackendAddressPool": "[resourceId(parameters('VirtualNetworkResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools', parameters('ApplicationGatewayName'), parameters('BackendAddressPool'))]",
```

I've also tried adding `parameters('SubscriptionName')` but the result is same.

```
"AppGatewayBackendAddressPool": "[resourceId(parameters('SubscriptionName') ,parameters('VirtualNetworkResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools', parameters('ApplicationGatewayName'), parameters('BackendAddressPool'))]",
```

When I declare variable like below then it applies backendAddressPool configuration in `Networking` -> `Load Balancing`.

```
"AppGatewayBackendAddressPool": [
        { "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<applicationGatewayName>/backendAddressPools/<backendAddressPool>" }
 ],
```

Similar I'm doing with `subnetRef` like below and that is working fine.

```
"subnetRef": "[resourceId(parameters('VirtualNetworkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('VirtualNetworkName'),  parameters('SubnetName'))]",
```

I want to parametrize the deployment by defining separate `parameters.json` file so I can attach `applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools` with different virtual machine scale sets.

Comment: Aren't you missing a concat for the variables?

Comment: Yes @KedMardemootoo It was concat function which I was missing in resource section. I've posted complete workaround as an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing the concat in the variables. Looking at the raw json on my end, this is how it's configured. See if you can do something similar, and convert the subnet name and backend address pool to variables.

```json
"ipConfigurations": [
    {
        "name": "ip-vmss-name",
        "properties": {
            "primary": true,
            "subnet": {
                "id": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet_externalid'), '/subnets/snet-vm')]"
            },
            "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
            "applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools": [
                {
                    "id": "[concat(parameters('applicationGateways_agw_1_externalid'), '/backendAddressPools/be-addr-pool-vmss-1')]"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved it by following [Ked Mardemootoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16046045/ked-mardemootoo) answer.

IP configuration section under `networkProfile` of VMSS resource.

```
"ipConfigurations": [
  {
      "name": "[concat(variables('VMSSName'), '-ipconfig')]",
      "properties": {
          "subnet": {
              "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
          },
          "applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools": [
              { "id": "[concat(parameters('AapplicationGatewayExternalid'), '/backendAddressPools/', parameters('BackendAddressPool'))]" }
          ]
      }
  }
]
```

Template file parameters:

```
        "BackendAddressPool": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Backend pool to host blue/green vmss."
            }
        },
        "AapplicationGatewayExternalid": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Application Gateway Id."
            }
        }
```

Now, ARM template is calling and referencing `applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools` attribute dynamically under VMSS' resource section.

I have these two parameters in `parameters.json` file where I can define values according to environment.

```
        "BackendAddressPool": {
            "value": "<backendPoolName>"
        },
        "AapplicationGatewayExternalid": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<ApplicationGatewayName>"
        }
```

Overriding template variables in release pipeline vars:
[overriding template vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwhHz.png)

Defining in pipeline vars
[pipeline var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSst3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong with your variables/parameters call but `applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools` is not a valid attribute for neither VMSS nor Application Gateway.

You can do it check [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters?tabs=json) and [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/applicationgateways?tabs=json) documentations. I achieve the same goal by setting `backendAddressPools`, which is in Application Gateway section, in different parameters.json files.

Comment: I'm still not sure then how the same `applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools` attribute is working fine when I declare variable as: `"AppGatewayBackendAddressPool": [
        { "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<applicationGatewayName>/backendAddressPools/<backendAddressPool>" }
 ],`